# ESRI QueryLayer + Javascript API - map displays inconsistent results

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query-layer

We recently migrated one of our map services from FGDB to an SQL Server spatial db backend. We are noticing a problem now in that the map appears to display locations inconsistently. I created a JSFiddle to demonstrate the issue and to simplify the code as much as possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/acurtiss/pbuLot1g/24/

If you zoom in or out, or simply re-run the application, you should see that some zip codes will randomly go blank. (The zip codes on this map should be nearly 100% filled in.) I have checked the JSON object returned from the map service and verified that the results are consistent and correct, so I'm beginning to suspect a problem with the Javascript API itself. I have contacted ESRI support and have a ticket open with them, but so far they haven't identified the source of the problem so I thought I would open this up to a broader set of GIS experts here on Stack Exchange.

As requested, here is a screenshot showing a significant number of blank zip codes. (Due to some limitations with my stack exchange account, apparently I can't post multiple screenshots, but hopefully this example shows the problem I'm trying to address.)

[image: blank zips]

Comment: Your map doesnt show in the link above using "https" as its requesting an  insecure stylesheet.  "http" works for me.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot or two with the problem you are seeing? I see some areas that don't have any color fill, but it's consistent as far as I can tell. Refreshed the page multiple times and even opened in a separate browser; the blank ones stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would check a few things:

1. What is the Pooling limit on this map service? There are a lot of simultaneous query requests going out, and you may be hitting the max instance limit, which causes some server responses to act funny. You can increase the max limit, or maybe switch your isolation settings to Low Isolation. (I've had bad luck with low isolation in the past, so this may not always work.)
2. I see some query responses marked `304 NOT MODIFIED` so you can try to dirty up your query, so it will always pull a result from the server.

You can do that here:

```
var dirty = (new Date()).getTime();
var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
query.returnGeometry = true;
query.maxAllowableOffset = 1000;  //not sure what the intent is here?
query.where = "NAME = '" + globals.siteFilter + "' AND " + dirty + "=" + dirty;
```

edit: After playing around with your JSFiddle (apologies for any server load!) I think the issue is your maximum pooling limit.

`MODE_SNAPSHOT` - As you noted in an above comment, this issue goes away using this mode, but it's a single request that pulls all the features at once and takes around 40-50 seconds to finish drawing. I can see why you wouldn't want this for production.

`MODE_ONDEMAND` - This breaks up the FeatureLayer query into smaller AOI queries. The upside is that you can potentially get your results faster if your FeatureLayer contains a lot of features. The downside is that the results only exist until the user pans/zooms the map again, which issues another set of queries. This increases load on the server.

I have a feeling that those 2 instances can't handle the number of queries being sent from your `MODE_ONDEMAND` features. I took one of the empty responses and plugged the parameters directly into the REST endpoint, and got back 137 features. Can you try raising the max pooling limit to 8 or 10?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried both of your suggestions but neither one made any apparent difference.

Comment: What's the pooling limit set at? Do you notice it coming close?

Comment: The only reason I don't think it's the API is because when I posted my comment above yesterday, I must have refreshed and zoomed around in the map 20 times on two different browsers, and 99% of the polygons remained filled and consistent. I tried again after you uploaded your screenshot, and it was obvious there were large chunks going missing. That makes it seem like a server config issue.

Comment: Pooling is set to Min 1 / Max 2 instances. I have never adjusted these values on our map services nor have we had issues like the problem I'm describing here. The confusing part is that, when those zip code chunks do go missing, they are actually showing up in the JSON object sent from the service. That was the main reason I was thinking it was somewhere downstream from the service, i.e., the API. But I'm at a loss right now, and I haven't heard from ESRI in a couple days.

Comment: I noticed on the queries, the JSON returned was mostly populated except on a few, it seemed the features returned at the very end were empty: `{ features: [ ] }` or something like that.

Comment: I've noticed that too. Going back to the Javascript API, I don't understand why it generates multiple (6?) queries to the REST service when zooming in or out, or just refreshing the layer. It appears the extent is the only thing that differs across these requests, but I would expect only one or two queries for this action.

Comment: I've edited my answer with some extra information, I think this is related to your max pooling for this service.

Comment: I really appreciate your interest in this issue. I raised the max pooling to 10 instances, and it seems to have had no effect.

Comment: Argh! I have a web app that works like yours and I ran across a similar issue. Raising the max pooling limit fixed my issue. If you log into the web Server Manager, is there any errors in the server logs for that service? If there's no errors or warnings there, I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: Nope, nothing at all in the logs. I also can't reproduce the error when I view the analogous map in ArcMap, which the folks at ESRI said would indicate a server / geodata problem rather than a Javascript API issue. Thanks again for your efforts in trying to solve this issue with me.

Answer (score -1):

I've had similar issues in the past with setting a layer definition or visibility while it was still drawing.  See this link: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/10158
Maybe that is your issue..

Comment: I'm afraid none of the suggestions provided in that thread made any difference. The only thing I've found that solves the problem is to use MODE_SNAPSHOT when creating the feature layer, but for various reasons we aren't able to use that mode for our production application (and it *should* work correctly regardless of the mode used).